# Mobile client complex authenticate to a server

Tags: android, authentication, encryption, passwords

I have a little complex situation:

I have a **mobile app** which is connecting to a server.
The server has a public file: password.txt
To access other files on the server, **the client needs to authenticate itself** (with a password). The user don't know that there is a password, the app has to have this password. (The public password file is needed, because the password could be changed, and if it's changed the password file is refreshed) [the password changing is not planned, but can happen rarely, with a random string, long story...] Every device the has this app is have to use the same password, the app could not have a login screen.

What is the best way to "encrypt" this password file, to not be trivial to access the other files?

- If the password.txt has the pure password, everybody can get it and access to other files
- If the password.txt has a modified password, that can be "decrypted" by a homemade method in the mobile app. But somebody can decompile the mobile app, and get the method...
- If the password.txt has an encrypted password, the mobile app has to have a password to decrypt the password.txt... So if you decomile the app, you have the password to the password.txt :D

**I think there is no good solution for this problem, there is no way to make it impossible, but I want to make it as hard as possible to "hack" it. What ideas have you got?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually obfuscation will be much better approach than even strongest ecryption - i.e.put some picture instead of the txt file read specific bytes, encode with base64 and use as password. As you have noticed - there is no secure method, since "security by obscurity" is in the fact "no security at all" after few hours with debugger and refactoring tools.